# Using Cauchy Residue Theorem Evaluate the Integral

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Evaluate the following integral using the Cauchy Residue Theorem

$$I=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{d\theta}{1-2a\cos{\theta}+a^2}, a>1$$

I'm not confident in my method to go about this. I think we make use of $z=e^{i\theta}$, which gives us $dz=id\theta e^{i\theta}=dz=izd\theta$. Additionally, we have $\cos{\theta}=\dfrac{e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}}{2}$. However, I think plugging these in makes the integral much more complicated than it needs to be, unless I'm doing something wrong.

$$I = \int_C\frac{-idz}{z(1-2a(\dfrac{z+z^{-1}}{2})+a^2)}=\int_C\frac{-idz}{z-az^2-a+a^2z}=\int_C\frac{-idz}{-az^2+(a^2+1)z-a}$$

Using the quadratic formula for the denominator, we get

$$z=\frac{-(a^2+1)\pm\sqrt{(a^2+1)^2-4(-a)(a)}}{2(-a)}=\frac{-(a^2+1)\pm\sqrt{a^4+6a^2+1}}{-2a}$$

I feel like this is too complex for this problem, maybe I missed something or I have to use quadratic formula again?

Comment: In your second line $z(1-2a(\dfrac{z+z^{-1}}{2})+a^2)=z-az^2\mathbf{-a}+a^2z$

Comment: In the third line $z=\frac{-(a^2+1)\pm\sqrt{(a^2+1)^2-4(-a)(\mathbf{-a})}}{2(-a)}=\frac{-(a^2+1)\pm\sqrt{(a^2+1)^2\mathbf{-4a^2}}}{2(-a)}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is computational, not conceptual. The roots of the quadratic polynomial $-az^2+(a^2+a)z-a$ are $a$ and $\frac1a$. So, if $a>1$, then\begin{align}\int_{-\pi}^\pi\frac{\mathrm d\theta}{1-2a\cos\theta+a^2}&=2\pi\operatorname{res}_{z=1/a}\frac1{-az^2+(a^2+a)z-a}\\&=2\pi\operatorname{res}_{z=1/a}\frac1{-a(z-a)\left(z-\frac1a\right)}\\&=\frac{2\pi}{-a\left(\frac1a-a\right)}\\&=\frac{2\pi}{a^2-1}.\end{align}